# In Makefiles, Is there a way to print the dollar sign ($) using @echo or $(info )?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have been trying to print the dollar sign ($) to stdout using `@echo` and `$(info )` used in a Makefile without success.

I can use the `echo` command in a bash shell on the command line to print the $ sign without any issues.  But the same bash commands do not work as expected when executed from within a Makefile.

The following is my test Makefile:

```
noecho:
    $(info Print the dollar sign using info: $)
    @echo You only see this!  You DO NOT see the echo command printed above.
    @echo Remember echo is a shell command. 
    @echo You may need to escape special characters, like \\
    @echo 'Or put put text in single quotes! No need to escape special characters like \.'
    @echo 
    @echo "Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of "
    @echo 'each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between '
    @echo 'single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.'
    @echo
    @echo "Double quotes can also be used in most cases."
    @echo "Enclosing characters in double quotes (\") preserves the literal value of "
    @echo "all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, \`, \\, and, "
    @echo "when history expansion is enabled, !"
    @echo 'Printing the $'
```

When I execute `make noecho`, I get:

```
rob$ make noecho
Print the dollar sign using info: 
You only see this! You DO NOT see the echo command printed above.
Remember echo is a shell command.
You may need to escape special characters, like \
Or put put text in single quotes! No need to escape special characters like \.

Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of 
each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between 
single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Double quotes can also be used in most cases.
Enclosing characters in double quotes (") preserves the literal value of 
all characters within the quotes, with the exception of  `, \, and, 
when history expansion is enabled, !
/opt/local/bin/bash: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/opt/local/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [noecho] Error 2
```

I also tried `@echo "'$'"` and `@echo "\$"` without success.

Is there a way to print the dollar sign ($) using `@echo` or `$(info )` in a Makefile?

Comment: This is make's doing, not that of bash (and even if it were otherwise, interpretation of makefiles doesn't use bash by default at all; the default shell invoked by `make` is `sh`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double the dollar sign to stop `make` from interpreting it

```
echo $$
$(info $$)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked!  I knew that there must be a simple solution.

Comment: I also just discovered that to print the dollar sign twice $$ using echo or @echo, one must use `$$\$$`, unless the dollar signs are enclosed in single quotes where `$$$$` works.    If you just use `$$$$` in an echo or @echo command without enclosing the dollar signs in single quotes, echo and @echo prints out a weird number instead.  Can anyone explain why that is the case?

Comment: `$$$$` is turned into `$$` which is a special shell variable containing the current PID.

Comment: Thanks again!   I forgot that $$ is a special shell variable representing  the PID of the process.

Comment: It doesn't matter that `$$` is a special shell variable... what matters is that `$` is special to the shell.  So the way to get make to escape a `$` to pass it to the shell is `$$`.  But the way to get the shell to escape a `$` to pass it to a program it invokes is to either use single quotes or a backslash.  Basically: first get your command line to work from your shell prompt.  Once that works, put it into your makefile recipe and change all `$` to `$$` and it will work there as well.

Comment: @MadScientist - Thanks.  I totally agree.  I just could not figure out how to get `make` to escape `$` until @choroba provided the solution.